# Core Data does not clean up External Binary Data after the objects are deleted?

Tags: ios, core-data

I use External Binary Data to store images in my app and found that these data files are not properly cleaned up after the objects owning the image attributes are deleted. Is it a known bug, or by design?

Comment: I've got the same and I think it's a bug. I resigned to use this feature at all. For me it wasn't well document, eg how it works with iCloud? Finally I've made own solution and store only a file name in coredata.